# In Laravel Eloquent, how do I reference primary query in subquery

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a model User that has many Orders. Orders have many products, with the pivot table order-product. I don't want to preload and iterate through the orders if at all possible.

I need to return users where

1. signed_date === true on User
2. order_date on Order is after signed_date on User
3. order-product shows product hasn't been paid

I am failing on number 2.
In the following code, the first query within whereHas is wrong. I don't know how to reference the signed date of the user from within the where has. If I was iterating through users in a collection I could do something like ($query) use $user, but how do I do this without preloading all the users?

```
return User::whereNotNull('signed_date')
           ->whereHas('orders', function ($query) {
               $query->where('order_date', '<=', 'user.signed_date');
               $query->whereHas('products', function ($q) {
                   $q->where('paid', false);
               });
           })
           ->get(['id','fname','lname', 'title', 'signed_date']);
```

I would like to use eloquent if possible. If that is not possible, I would be happy for tips in solving this problem using the query builder/sql.

Comment: `whereHas` is not a sub-query. It's a separate query so you can't really combine them

Comment: I wasn't sure on terminology. How would you accomplish what I am trying without preloading all the users?

Comment: @Namoshek Thank you, it works. Please post your previous comment as an answer and I will Accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eloquent query builder has a special function called `whereColumn('a', '<=', 'b')` to compare columns instead of a column against a value. Using this function instead of a normal `where()` is necessary because of the way the query builder builds the actual query. You need to let the query builder know that you are going to pass a column name instead of a value for proper escaping and formatting of the query string.

Anyway, it seems you can also pass column names prefixed with a table name to the function, allowing you to compare columns across tables:

```
$query->whereColumn('orders.order_date', '<=', 'users.signed_date')
```

This works because you are using `whereHas()` in your query. Your query basically gets translated to:

```
SELECT id, fname, lname, title, signed_date
FROM users
WHERE signed_date NOT NULL
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM orders
    WHERE orders.order_date <= users.signed_date
      AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM products
        WHERE paid = 0
      )
  )
```

It might actually be not necessary at all to use the table name together with the column name in `whereColumn()`. But in case you'll ever add a column named the same on another table, the query might break - so IMHO it is good practice to use the table name in custom queries.

---

By the way, the reason this will not work together with `with('relationship')` is that this function results in an additional query and you obviously cannot compare columns across queries. Imagine the following:

```
Order::with('user')->take(5)->get();
```

It will be translated into the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
LIMIT 5

SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

where the five `?` will be the `user_id`s of the orders. If the first query returns multiple rows with the same `user_id`, the amount of rows fetched from the users table gets reduced of course.

*Note: All the queries are only examples. Might be that the query builder builds different queries based on the database type and/or escapes them differently (i.e. column names in backticks).*